# Fabric doesn't show latest iPhone App build by Xcode(6.4)

Tags: xcode, twitter-fabric

My coworker set up the Xcode+Fabric environment before he left, and we have several old build shown in Fabric, which we were able to distribute to team members.

Now I did a new build (say build 21) within Xcode and I'm able to run with iPhone simulator and it indeed shows build 21 there. But when I open fabric from the menu bar I still only see the old build 20.

Is there an additional step I need to do to make build 21 show up within Fabric thus we can distribute this new version?

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long have you been trying?  One known trick is that Fabric sometimes needs you to exit the app (as in return to the home screen, not just kill it in Xcode) and re-open to "push" the data up to the server.  Have you tried running it on a device, running the app, then returning to the home screen and re-opening the app, just to slap the proverbial jukebox and make Fabric do its thing?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm brand new with this environment so please bear with me. So you suggest to trigger build and run the app on my iPhone (not the simulator) from within Xcode, then kill the app on the iPhone by going back to home screen, right? I tried to do that, but got a "App installation failed. The application could not be verified." from Xcode. When run in iOS simulator everything is fine. Any suggestions?